# The effect of filtering a general input time function $f(t)$ by $g(t)$, with $g(t)$ being the Gaussian function

Tags: normal-distribution, convolution

I am asked to explain the effect of filtering a general input time function $f(t)$ by $g(t)$ (which is just the convolution of $f(t)$ with $g(t)$), with $g(t)$ being the Gaussian function as below: $$g(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}t_{H}}e^{-(t/t_{H})^2}$$
where $t_H$ is the half duration, a constant.

I have no idea how to answer this since I am very new to concepts like convolution and Gaussian functions. Is there any help or hint?

Comment: In terms of Fourier transforms the resulting signal has spectrum $F(\omega)G(\omega)$. Compute $G$ and interpret what it does to the high frequencies of the input signal.

Comment: @Aruralreader Could you please offer the direct explanation? I am too new to this topic and I can't fully understand what you said....